# How to prevent nginx throttling conflicting with maintenance mode?

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting, maintenance, throttling

We use the [HttpLimitReqModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLimitReqModule) nginx mondule for rate throttling and have found that it conflicts with our "*maintenance mode*" because both components are using [http status code 503](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

When throttling is activated (via the [limit_req](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLimitReqModule) directive), nginx would normally serve a 503, but unfortunatly our maintenance mode location is used, which results in a 302 to our Amazon S3 hosted maintenance page. **A 302 for a throttled request is not a good outcome**.

I was wondering how other people deal with this issue? Should I for example use a different status code for our maintenance page, but if so, what?

Ideally for throttled requests, I don't want any page served, only a 503 response header - it needs to be as lightweight as possible because the whole point is to stop the server being overwhelmed.

---

For reference, this is the nginx config that we use for "Maintenance Mode":

```
server {
    ...

    # Redirect processing of 503 error pages into a named location:
    error_page 503 @maintenance;

    # "Maintenance Mode" is off by default - Use a nginx variable to track state.
    set $maintenance off;

    # Switch on "Maintenance Mode" if a certain file exists.
    if (-f /var/www/mysite/shared/maintenanceON) {
        set $maintenance on;
    }

    if ($maintenance = on) {
        return 503; # 503 - Service unavailable
    }

    location @maintenance {
        # Redirect the request to our maintenance page in Amazon S3.
        rewrite ^(.*)$ http://mysite.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ break;
    }
    ...
    # Process the php files - pass to php-fpm.
    location ~ \.php {
        # Limit aggressive bots and crawlers to 30 requests per minute.
        limit_req zone=bots;

        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:$fastcgi_port;
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nginx 1.3.15 there is a "[limit_req_status](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html#limit_req_status)" directive that allows you to specify the http response code that the throttler will return.

```
# Define a limit request zone called "bots" that will track requests by IP.
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=bots:20m rate=15r/s;

# 429 = Too Many Requests
limit_req_status 429;
```

http status 429 means "`Too Many Requests`" - This code has been accepted in [RFC 6585](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#page-3) *Additional HTTP Status Codes*. It is used, for example, on the [Twitter REST API Rate Limiter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1).

([Michael's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/554748/21415) also works because in my config 503 is only used internally by nginx).

Answer (score 4):

Use a status code other than 503 for your "maintenance mode."

As we can clearly see, users don't actually get served a 503 when you are using "maintenance mode" anyway, so there's no benefit to using that status code internally in your configuration. Make up another code (593?) and use that.

---

Or better yet, skip the extra `location` and just send the `rewrite` directly when the maintenance file exists.

```
    if (-f /var/www/mysite/shared/maintenanceON) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ http://mysite.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ redirect;
    }
```